# Redirect my domaine homepage to another url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect my domaine homepage to another url ?

For example, I want `domain.com` to `domain.com/en/`.

I already try:
`RewriteRule ^index.php /en/ [R=301]`

But it don't work.

Comment: you meant only home page , so domain.com will be domain.com/eng/ and domain.com/index.php will be domain.com/en/index.php but other pages as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule to redirect landing page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /en/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok but I now have a conflict with this rule : `RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]`. How can I solve this please?

Comment: Ok but now I have this URL type `http://domain.com/index.php?lang=en` whereas I would like if possible `http://domain.com/en/`.

Comment: It is better to put all the requirements at one place in question rather than in comments. Try my updated code in the given order and test after clearing browser cache.